# Add a cell formula in Excel via vba

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I’m not an Excel or VBA expert but I want to insert this current excel formula into cell’s using VBA.

Current Excel formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUM(D570)=FALSE;ISNUM(D573)=FALSE);"";IF(C573="Total";D573-D570;""))
```

VBA formula :

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("a" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 12).Value = "=IF(OR(ISNUM(R[-3]C[-9])=FALSE;ISNUM(R[0]C[-9])=FALSE);'';IF(R[0]C[-10]='Total';R[0]C[-9]-R[-3]C[-9];''))"
```

It doesn’t work… Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 8):

Try using `.formula =` instead of `.value =` in your VBA code.

Setting the `.value` of a cell simply copies in whatever value you specify. In this case, your formula is simply converted to a string value.

Using the `.formula` property, you are actually specifying the formula that gets used to *compute* the value, which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Can I first suggest a simplification of your formula, from:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUM(D570)=FALSE;ISNUM(D573)=FALSE);"";IF(C573="Total";D573-D570;""))
```

...to...

```
=IF(AND(C573="Total"; ISNUM(D570); ISNUM(D573)); D573-D570; "")
```

Then, I'd set a cell (the active cell in the example below) to use that formula using the VBA code:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(...)"
```

Comment: Also change the semicolons to commas.