# String that contains bracket

Tags: vba

I want to write an equation into an excel cell like: `Cells(1, 1).Value = "=IF()"`. But the compiler gives me an error message as `Application-defined or object-defined error`. When I remove the brackets, there's no error any more. How can I have a bracket in VBA string?

I've also tried to use Chr(40) to replace `(`, but it doesn't work.

After further debugging, I see that if I change `IF` to an arbitrary string, it works. But if I change it to another function name, like LEFT, there's an error. Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you want to really put just a string or a formula? If it is the latter, use `.Formula` property. Something like: `Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=IF(A1,,)"`. Take note of the syntax of the formula you're using also. If it is wrong, then error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ton of experience with this stuff, but if I remember correctly, you're looking for the `.Formula` property, rather than `.Value`.

```
Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=IF()"
```

**Edit:**

I just noticed that this was also earlier suggested in a comment by user L42. You can also see this in use here: [Add a cell formula in Excel via vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028160/add-a-cell-formula-in-excel-via-vba).